# ASP.NET MVC add-migration. Project failed to build

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to enable migrations for data entity: In Package Manager Console:

`Enable-Migrations -ProjectName Vidly -ContextTypeName Vidly.Models.MyDBContext`

I get:

```
Code First Migrations enabled for project Vidly.
```

Then

```
add-migration 'InitialModel'
```

I get: "The project 'Vidly' failed to build."

My Configuration.cs:

```
namespace Vidly.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Vidly.Models.MyDBContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Vidly.Models.MyDBContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        }
    }
}
```

And my MyDBContext.cs is

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace Vidly.Models
{
    public class MyDBContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } // My domain models
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }// My domain models
    }
}
```

The error message is:

> error CS0311: The type 'Vidly.Models.MyDBContext' cannot be used as
>   type parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'DbMigrationsConfiguration'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'Vidly.Models.MyDBContext' to
>   'System.Data.Entity.DbContext'.

It seems I cannot use MyDBContext as a type super class in Configuration.cs.
Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing to implement `DbContext`.

Change AND try:

```
public class MyDBContext:DBContext
    {
        public  MyDBContext() : base("ConnectionStringName")
        {           
        }
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } // My domain models
        public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }// My domain models
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things you are missing here.

1. Inheriting from `DBContext`
2. Constructor to pass the name of connection string entry you used in

use below snippet of code. note: replace `VidlyDBConnectionString` with your connection string name

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    namespace Vidly.Models
    {
        public class MyDBContext :DbContext
         {

            public MyDBContext():base("name=VidlyDBConnectionString")
            {
             }
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } // My domain models
            public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; }// My domain models


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace Vidly.Models;
   {
        public class MyDBContext :DbContext
         {
            public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; } // My domain models
            public DbSet<Movie> Movies { get; set; } // My domain models
         }

   }
```

Comment: This should solve your problem. Let us know is it works.